# Critical points of ${f}(x,y)=(x+2y)e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}$

Tags: functions, derivatives, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I know how to find the critical point but i can't solve the system.
This is the function ${f}(x,y)=(x+2y)e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}$
This is the first derivative of x:
$${f}'x = (x+2y)'e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} + (x+2y){e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}}'$$
$${f}'x = 1e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} + (x+2y)(e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}})(-2x) $$
$${f}'x = 1e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} - (2x^2 + 4xy)(e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}$$
$${f}'x = e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} (1-2x^2 + 4xy)$$
This is the first derivative of y:
$${f}'y = (x+2y)'e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} + (x+2y){e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}}'$$
$${f}'y = 2e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} + (x+2y)(e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}})(-2y)$$
$${f}'y = 1e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} - (2xy + 4y^2)(e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}$$
$${f}'y = e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} (2-2xy - 4y)$$
The system is:
\begin{vmatrix}
{f}'x = e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} (1-2x^2 + 4xy) = 0\\
{f}'y =e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}} (2-2xy - 4y)= 0
\end{vmatrix}
The problem is that I can't solve the system...

Comment: Since an exponential is ner zero, the factors inside brackets must be.

Comment: The $x$-derive of $x^2-y^2$ is $2x$, but you have $x^{-2}-y^{-2}$

Comment: can you explain it again

Comment: The partial differential of $e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}$ with respect to $ x$ is not $e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}(-2x)$. It is $e^{x^{-2}-y^{-2}}(-2x^{-3}).$